# Xpath expression with OR

Tags: xpath

I'd like to know if there is a way to verify multiple strings on a Xpath. This is the one I'm using now:

```
/td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word1')]]
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
/td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word1' OR 'Word2' OR 'Word3')]]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

I believe, the problem why you are experiencing is *case-sensitivity*, try writing `or` in lower-case:

```
//td[text()[contains(.,'Word1') or contains(.,'Word2') or contains(.,'Word3')]]
```

If it doesn't help, you can use `Union` approach:

```
/td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word1')]] | /td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word2')]] | /td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word3')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible:

```
/td[2][text()[contains(.,'Word1') OR contains(.,'Word2') OR contains(.,'Word3')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you just need separate `contains()` calls:

```
[contains(., 'Word1') OR contains(., 'Word2') OR contains(., 'Word3')]
```

As you have it currently, a boolean being passed as the second parameter to `contains`, rather than a string.

Comment: I'm getting this error --> **[error] Invalid xpath [2]: /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2][text()[contains(., 'FirstLine') OR contains(., 'SecondLine')]]** -- Did I write something wrong?

Comment: Try `/td[2][contains(.,'Word1') OR contains(.,'Word2') OR contains(.,'Word3')]`

Comment: Same error -- **[error] Invalid xpath [2]: /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2][contains(., 'FirstLine') OR contains(., 'SecondLine')]** -- is there something I can check to help you? I forgot to mention, I'm using Selenium IDE, not sure how it handles Xpath, I may ask it as a Selenium IDE question if we can't make it work

Comment: Looks valid to me but it's a while since I did XPath. Sorry, I'm afraid I can't help further.

Comment: It's correct except that "or" must be in lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

With **XPath 2.0 or 3.0**  you could also use:

- A [Quantified Expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions) to loop over a sequence of words and test if any of the words are contained

  `//td[2][text()[some $word in ('Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3') satisfies contains(., $word)]]`
- The [matches()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function and specify your list of words in a regex:

  `//td[2][text()[matches(., 'Word1|Word2|Word3')]]`